# How to fit a long horizontal table

Tags: longtable

Hello1 I'm trying to compile a long and wide horizontal table. I'm not sure if it fits the page. I tried many things but until now I haven't got any close result. Picture follow. I could really use some advices! The l and Y were chosen randomly...

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,
12pt,
twoside,
BCOR10mm,
pagesize,
bibliography=totoc,
listof=totoc,
1.5headlines]{report} %{scrreprt}
\usepackage[left=3cm,right=3cm,top=3cm,bottom=3cm, bindingoffset=6mm]{geometry} 

\setlength{\headheight}{14.49998pt}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Insert images
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}
\raggedbottom


\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xltabular} % for 'xltabular' environment
\usepackage{booktabs}  % for well-spaced horizontal rules
\usepackage{amsmath}% for \smash[b] macro
\usepackage[skip=0.333\baselineskip]{caption}
\usepackage{ragged2e}  % \Centering & \RaggedRight macros

\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X} %
\newcolumntype{P}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{\hsize}} %
\newcolumntype{Z}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X} %
\newcolumntype{Q}{>{\Centering}p{\hsize}}

\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{ragged2e} 
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, tabularx} 

\usepackage{siunitx}   % for S type columns 

\begin{document}

\begin{adjustbox}{angle=90}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}
{@{}llYYlllYYl@{}} 
\toprule
market\_area\_1 &  ag.unit & hydro. system &h Hydro\_plant\_name & hydro\_plant\_type &  commissioning\_date &  hydraulic\_head [m] &  power\_turbine\_max [MW] &  full\_load\_hours\_turbine &  annual\_generation [GWh/a] & turbine\_type \\
\midrule
 CHL1 & 0 & CONECTIVIDAD\_MAULE & HE\_LOS\_CONDORES & conventionalHydroStorage & 2023.0 & 480.00 &150.00 &3601.64 & 540.25 &peltonTurbine \\
 CHL1 & 0 & CONECTIVIDAD\_MAULE &HE\_CIPRESES & conventionalHydroStorage & 1995.0 & 370.00 &105.82 &1814.46 & 192.01 &peltonTurbine \\
 CHL1 & 0 & CONECTIVIDAD\_MAULE & HP\_LA\_MINA & conventionalHydroStorage & 2018.0 &64.82 & 36.70 &1788.48 &  65.64 & francisTurbine \\
 CHL1 & 0 & CONECTIVIDAD\_MAULE & HP\_OJOS\_DE\_AGUA & conventionalHydroStorage & 2008.0 &65.96 &8.98 &4289.62 &  38.54 & francisTurbine \\
 CHL1 & 0 & CONECTIVIDAD\_MAULE & HP\_ISLA & conventionalHydroStorage & 1963.0 &92.11 & 69.00 &4719.75 & 325.66 & francisTurbine \\
 CHL1 & 0 & CONECTIVIDAD\_MAULE &  HP\_CURILLINQUE & conventionalHydroStorage & 1993.0 & 114.86 & 91.77 &4227.24 & 387.93 & francisTurbine \\
 CHL1 & 0 & CONECTIVIDAD\_MAULE & HP\_LOMA\_ALTA & conventionalHydroStorage & 1997.0 &51.17 & 39.93 &4172.54 & 166.62 & francisTurbine \\
 CHL1 & 0 & CONECTIVIDAD\_MAULE &  HP\_LOS\_HIERROS & conventionalHydroStorage & 2014.0 & 102.35 & 25.00 &3904.58 &  97.61 & francisTurbine \\
 CHL1 & 0 & CONECTIVIDAD\_MAULE & HP\_LOS\_HIERROS\_II & conventionalHydroStorage & 2015.0 &23.87 &6.00 &3085.52 &  18.51 & aggregatedTurbine \\
 CHL1 & 0 & CONECTIVIDAD\_MAULE & HP\_PEHUENCHE & conventionalHydroStorage & 1991.0 & 202.43 &568.29 &2110.01 &1199.10 & francisTurbine \\
 CHL1 & 0 & CONECTIVIDAD\_MAULE &  HE\_COLBUN & conventionalHydroStorage & 1985.0 & 171.43 &460.80 &2965.72 &1366.60 & francisTurbine \\
 CHL1 & 0 & CONECTIVIDAD\_MAULE & HP\_MACHICURA & conventionalHydroStorage & 1985.0 &37.53 & 94.76 &3152.45 & 298.73 & aggregatedTurbine \\
 CHL1 & 0 & CONECTIVIDAD\_MAULE &  HP\_SAN\_IGNACIO & conventionalHydroStorage & 1996.0 &21.61 & 36.91 &3191.41 & 117.81 & aggregatedTurbine \\
 CHL1 & 0 & CONECTIVIDAD\_MAULE &HP\_CHIBURGO & conventionalHydroStorage & 2007.0 & 110.33 & 19.16 &2767.31 &  53.01 & francisTurbine \\
 CHL1 & 0 & CONECTIVIDAD\_MAULE & HP\_SAN\_CLEMENTE & conventionalHydroStorage & 2010.0 &36.84 &5.89 &2201.96 &  12.96 & aggregatedTurbine \\
 CHL1 & 0 &  CONECTIVIDAD\_LAJA & HE\_EL\_TORO & conventionalHydroStorage & 1973.0 & 616.00 &448.74 &1807.75 & 811.21 &peltonTurbine \\
 CHL1 & 0 &  CONECTIVIDAD\_LAJA & HP\_ABANICO & conventionalHydroStorage & 1948.0 & 136.47 & 92.71 &2332.72 & 216.27 & francisTurbine \\
 CHL1 & 0 &  CONECTIVIDAD\_LAJA &  HE\_ANTUCO & conventionalHydroStorage & 1981.0 & 181.95 &319.17 &3237.69 &1033.37 & francisTurbine \\
 CHL1 & 0 &  CONECTIVIDAD\_LAJA &HP\_RUCUE & conventionalHydroStorage & 1998.0 & 145.56 &178.13 &3306.83 & 589.05 & francisTurbine \\
 CHL1 & 0 &  CONECTIVIDAD\_LAJA &HP\_QUILLECO & conventionalHydroStorage & 2007.0 &62.55 & 70.65 &3418.37 & 241.51 & francisTurbine \\
 CHL1 & 0 &  CONECTIVIDAD\_LAJA &  HP\_LAJA\_I & conventionalHydroStorage & 2015.0 &15.58 & 34.06 &1779.08 &  60.59 & aggregatedTurbine \\
 CHL1 & 0 & CONECTIVIDAD\_BIO\_BIO &HE\_RALCO & conventionalHydroStorage & 2004.0 & 181.41 &688.96 &2481.89 &1709.94 & francisTurbine \\
 CHL1 & 0 & CONECTIVIDAD\_BIO\_BIO &HP\_PALMUCHO & conventionalHydroStorage & 2007.0 & 129.98 & 31.95 &6031.07 & 192.70 & francisTurbine \\
 CHL1 & 0 & CONECTIVIDAD\_BIO\_BIO &  HE\_PANGUE & conventionalHydroStorage & 1996.0 &90.98 &465.83 &2633.81 &1226.91 & francisTurbine \\
 CHL1 & 0 & CONECTIVIDAD\_BIO\_BIO & HE\_ANGOSTURA & conventionalHydroStorage & 2014.0 &48.90 &321.00 &2802.40 & 899.57 & francisTurbine \\
 CHL1 & 0 &  CONECTIVIDAD\_ACONCAGUA &HP\_HORNITOS & conventionalHydroStorage & 2008.0 & 568.67 & 60.85 &2724.46 & 165.78 &peltonTurbine \\
 CHL1 & 0 &  CONECTIVIDAD\_ACONCAGUA &  HP\_JUNCAL & conventionalHydroStorage & 1994.0 & 250.20 & 32.00 &7021.31 & 224.68 & francisTurbine \\
 CHL1 & 0 &  CONECTIVIDAD\_ACONCAGUA &  HP\_BLANCO & conventionalHydroStorage & 1993.0 & 655.07 & 52.87 &2546.76 & 134.64 &peltonTurbine \\
 CHL1 & 0 &  CONECTIVIDAD\_ACONCAGUA &HP\_LOS\_QUILOS & conventionalHydroStorage & 1943.0 & 216.07 & 39.80 &4461.21 & 177.56 & francisTurbine \\
 CHL1 & 0 &  CONECTIVIDAD\_ACONCAGUA & HP\_CHACABUQUITO & conventionalHydroStorage & 2002.0 & 138.76 & 25.64 &3413.85 &  87.52 & francisTurbine \\
 CHL1 & 0 &  CONECTIVIDAD\_TINGUIRIRICA\_I &HP\_LA\_HIGUERA & conventionalHydroStorage & 2011.0 & 354.84 &154.61 &2939.04 & 454.41 & francisTurbine \\
 CHL1 & 0 & CONECTIVIDAD\_TINGUIRIRICA\_II & HP\_LA\_CONFLUENCIA & conventionalHydroStorage & 2011.0 & 353.72 &162.79 &2000.48 & 325.66 & francisTurbine \\
 CHL1 & 0 & CONECTIVIDAD\_PILMAIQUEN &HE\_PILMAIQUEN & conventionalHydroStorage & 1944.0 &30.70 & 40.68 &4716.68 & 191.86 & aggregatedTurbine \\
 CHL1 & 0 & CONECTIVIDAD\_PILMAIQUEN &HP\_RUCATAYO & conventionalHydroStorage & 2012.0 &35.82 & 59.30 &3490.90 & 207.01 & aggregatedTurbine \\
 CHL1 & 0 & CONECTIVIDAD\_RAPEL &HE\_RAPEL & conventionalHydroStorage & 1986.0 &70.49 &376.64 &1340.55 & 504.90 & francisTurbine \\
 CHL1 & 0 &CANUTILAR &HE\_CANUTILLAR & conventionalHydroStorage & 1990.0 & 229.89 &171.57 &4066.02 & 697.61 & francisTurbine \\
 CHL1 & 1 &  SIC\_BIG &  SIC\_AGGREGATED\_B\_run\_of\_river &  runOfTheRiver &  NaN & 1.00 &  1285.44 &2945.27 &3785.97 & aggregatedTurbine \\
 CHL1 & 1 &SIC\_SMALL &  SIC\_AGGREGATED\_S\_run\_of\_river &  runOfTheRiver &  NaN & 1.00 &511.61 &2945.27 &1506.84 & aggregatedTurbine \\
 CHL0 & 1 & SING\_BIG & SING\_AGGREGATED\_B\_run\_of\_river &  runOfTheRiver &  NaN & 1.00 & 10.83 &2524.52 &  27.35 & aggregatedTurbine \\
 CHL0 & 1 & SING\_SMALL & SING\_AGGREGATED\_S\_run\_of\_river &  runOfTheRiver &  NaN & 1.00 &6.55 &2524.52 &  16.54 & aggregatedTurbine \\
 CHL2 & 1 &DECENTRAL &Decentral\_all\_run\_of\_river &  runOfTheRiver &  NaN & 1.00 & 24.08 &2524.52 &  60.80 & aggregatedTurbine \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\end{adjustbox}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To long for the comment:

- your table is too huge that can be easy fit on page
- table contain an error: you define 10 columns, but use 11
- why you use long word column headers, for example `full\_load\_hours\_turbine`? Reconsider, that `full load hours turbine` is more natural and readable, and also can be split in multi line cell,
- numbers will be easier to compare if they will be aligned at decimal points
- etc

A possible solution with ugly result is to use of rotate cells headers:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand\theadfont{}
\usepackage{booktabs}  % for well-spaced horizontal rules


\begin{document}
    \begin{sidewaystable}
    \scriptsize
\settowidth\rotheadsize{full\_load\_hours\_turbine}
\renewcommand\cellalign{bl}
\begin{tabular}{@{} *{11}{l} @{} }%{\linewidth}{@{} ll YY lll YY c l@{}}
    \toprule
\rothead{market\_area\_1}
    &  \rothead{ag.unit} 
        &  \rothead{hydro. system} 
            &  \rothead{h Hydro\_plant\_name}
                &  \rothead{hydro\_plant\_type} 
                    &  \rothead{commissioning\_date}
                        &  \rothead{hydraulic\_head [m]} 
                            &  \rothead{power\_turbine\_max [MW]} 
                                &  \rothead{full\_load\_hours\_turbine} 
                                    &  \rothead{annual\_generation [GWh/a]} 
                                        &  \rothead{turbine\_type}     \\
    \midrule
CHL1    & 0 & CONECTIVIDAD\_MAULE 
                & HE\_LOS\_CONDORES 
                    & conventionalHydroStorage 
                        & 2023.0 
                            & 480.00 
                                &150.00 
                                    &3601.64 
                                        & 540.25 
                                            & peltonTurbine         \\
% rest of table body
\end{tabular}
    \end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

which gives

[image]

You really need to reconsider to redesign your table. For example, split it in two tables, where remove fourth column from table and move their content to their table caption, and also consider afore comments.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{ragged2e} 
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs, tabularx} 
\newcommand\mcx[1]{\multicolumn{1}{>{\Centering}X}{#1}}
\usepackage{siunitx}   % for S type columns 

\begin{document}
    \begin{sidewaystable}
    \small
    \setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} *{2}{>{\centering}p{3em}}
                                 *{2}{l}
                                 *{5}{S[table-format=4.2]}
                              >{\quad}l
                             @{} }
    \toprule
market area 1
    &   ag.\newline unit 
        &   hydro. system
            &   Hydro plant name
                    &  \mcx{Commi\-ssioning date}
                        &  \mcx{Hydraulic head [m]}
                            &  \mcx{Power turbine max [MW]}
                                &   \mcx{Full load hours turbine}
                                    &   \mcx{Annual generation [GWh/a]}
                                        &   \mcx{Turbine type}      \\
    \hline
    \rowcolor{gray!10}
\multicolumn{10}{l}{Hydro plant type: Conventional hydro storage}   \\
    \hline
CHL1    & 0 & CONECTIVIDAD MAULE 
                & HE LOS CONDORES 
                        & 2023.0 
                            & 480.00 
                                & 150.00 
                                    & 3601.64 
                                        & 540.25 
                                            & Pelton              \\
CHL1 & 0 & CONECTIVIDAD MAULE & HE CIPRESES  
     & 1995.0 & 370.00 & 105.82 & 1814.46 & 192.01 & Pelton      \\
CHL1 & 0 & CONECTIVIDAD MAULE & HP LA MINA  
     & 2018.0 &  64.82 &   36.70 & 1788.48 &  65.64 & Francis      \\
CHL1 & 0 & CONECTIVIDAD MAULE & HP OJOS DE AGUA  
     & 2008.0 &  65.96 & 8.98 & 4289.62 &  38.54 & Francis       \\
CHL1 & 0 & CONECTIVIDAD MAULE & HP ISLA  
     & 1963.0 &  92.11 & 69.00 & 4719.75 & 325.66 & Francis      \\
CHL1 & 0 & CONECTIVIDAD MAULE &  HP CURILLINQUE  
     & 1993.0 & 114.86 & 91.77 & 4227.24 & 387.93 & Francis      \\
CHL1 & 0 & CONECTIVIDAD MAULE & HP LOMA ALTA  
     & 1997.0 &  51.17 & 39.93 & 4172.54 & 166.62 & Francis      \\
CHL1 & 0 & CONECTIVIDAD MAULE &  HP LOS HIERROS  
     & 2014.0 & 102.35 & 25.00 & 3904.58 &  97.61 & Francis      \\
CHL1 & 0 & CONECTIVIDAD MAULE & HP LOS HIERROS II  
     & 2015.0 &  23.87 &  6.00 & 3085.52 &  18.51 & aggregated   \\
CHL1 & 0 & CONECTIVIDAD MAULE & HP PEHUENCHE  
     & 1991.0 & 202.43 & 568.29 & 2110.01 & 1199.10 & Francis      \\
CHL1 & 0 & CONECTIVIDAD MAULE &  HE COLBUN  
     & 1985.0 & 171.43 & 460.80 & 2965.72 & 1366.60 & Francis      \\
CHL1 & 0 & CONECTIVIDAD MAULE & HP MACHICURA  
     & 1985.0 &  37.53 & 94.76 & 3152.45 & 298.73 & aggregated   \\
CHL1 & 0 & CONECTIVIDAD MAULE &  HP SAN IGNACIO  
     & 1996.0 &  21.61 & 36.91 & 3191.41 & 117.81 & aggregated   \\
CHL1 & 0 & CONECTIVIDAD MAULE &HP CHIBURGO  
     & 2007.0 & 110.33 & 19.16 & 2767.31 &  53.01 & Francis      \\
CHL1 & 0 & CONECTIVIDAD MAULE & HP SAN CLEMENTE  
     & 2010.0 &  36.84 &  5.89 & 2201.96 &  12.96 & aggregated   \\
CHL1 & 0 &  CONECTIVIDAD LAJA & HE EL TORO  
     & 1973.0 & 616.00 & 448.74 & 1807.75 & 811.21 & Pelton      \\
CHL1 & 0 &  CONECTIVIDAD LAJA & HP ABANICO  
     & 1948.0 & 136.47 &  92.71 & 2332.72 & 216.27 & Francis      \\
CHL1 & 0 &  CONECTIVIDAD LAJA &  HE ANTUCO  
     & 1981.0 & 181.95 & 319.17 & 3237.69 & 1033.37 & Francis      \\
CHL1 & 0 &  CONECTIVIDAD LAJA & HP RUCUE  
     & 1998.0 & 145.56 & 178.13 & 3306.83 & 589.05 & Francis      \\
CHL1 & 0 &  CONECTIVIDAD LAJA &HP QUILLECO  
     & 2007.0 &  62.55 &  70.65 & 3418.37 &  241.51 & Francis      \\
CHL1 & 0 &  CONECTIVIDAD LAJA &  HP LAJA I  
     & 2015.0 &  15.58 &  34.06 & 1779.08 &  60.59 & aggregated   \\
CHL1 & 0 & CONECTIVIDAD BIO BIO & HE RALCO  
     & 2004.0 & 181.41 & 688.96 & 2481.89 & 1709.94 & Francis      \\
CHL1 & 0 & CONECTIVIDAD BIO BIO & HP PALMUCHO  
     & 2007.0 & 129.98 &  31.95 & 6031.07 & 192.70 & Francis      \\
CHL1 & 0 & CONECTIVIDAD BIO BIO &  HE PANGUE  
     & 1996.0 &  90.98 & 465.83 & 2633.81 & 1226.91 & Francis      \\
CHL1 & 0 & CONECTIVIDAD BIO BIO & HE ANGOSTURA  
     & 2014.0 &  48.90 & 321.00 & 2802.40 & 899.57 & Francis      \\
CHL1 & 0 &  CONECTIVIDAD ACONCAGUA & HP HORNITOS 
     & 2008.0 & 568.67 &  60.85 & 2724.46 & 165.78 & Pelton      \\
CHL1 & 0 &  CONECTIVIDAD ACONCAGUA &  HP JUNCAL  
     & 1994.0 & 250.20 &  32.00 & 7021.31 & 224.68 & Francis      \\
CHL1 & 0 &  CONECTIVIDAD ACONCAGUA &  HP BLANCO 
     & 1993.0 & 655.07 &  52.87 & 2546.76 & 134.64 & Pelton      \\
CHL1 & 0 &  CONECTIVIDAD ACONCAGUA & HP LOS QUILOS  
     & 1943.0 & 216.07 &  39.80 & 4461.21 & 177.56 & Francis      \\
CHL1 & 0 &  CONECTIVIDAD ACONCAGUA & HP CHACABUQUITO 
     & 2002.0 & 138.76 &  25.64 & 3413.85 &  87.52 & Francis      \\
CHL1 & 0 &  CONECTIVIDAD TINGUIRIRICA I & HP LA HIGUERA 
     & 2011.0 & 354.84 & 154.61 & 2939.04 & 454.41 & Francis      \\
CHL1 & 0 & CONECTIVIDAD TINGUIRIRICA II & HP LA CONFLUENCIA 
     & 2011.0 & 353.72 & 162.79 & 2000.48 & 325.66 & Francis      \\
CHL1 & 0 & CONECTIVIDAD PILMAIQUEN & HE PILMAIQUEN  
     & 1944.0 &  30.70 &  40.68 & 4716.68 & 191.86 & aggregated   \\
CHL1 & 0 & CONECTIVIDAD PILMAIQUEN & HP RUCATAYO  
     & 2012.0 &  35.82 &  59.30 & 3490.90 & 207.01 & aggregated   \\
CHL1 & 0 & CONECTIVIDAD RAPEL &HE RAPEL  
     & 1986.0 &  70.49 & 376.64 & 1340.55 & 504.90 & Francis      \\
CHL1 & 0 & CANUTILAR & HE CANUTILLAR  
     & 1990.0 & 229.89 & 171.57 & 4066.02 & 697.61 & Francis      \\
    \hline
\rowcolor{gray!10}
\multicolumn{10}{l}{Hydro plant type: Run of the river}                 \\
    \hline
CHL1 & 1 &  SIC BIG &  SIC AGGREGATED B
     &  {NaN} &   1.00 & 1285.44 & 2945.27 & 3785.97 & aggregated   \\
CHL1 & 1 & SIC SMALL & SIC AGGREGATED S
     &  {NaN} &   1.00 &  511.61 & 2945.27 & 1506.84 & aggregated   \\
CHL0 & 1 & SING BIG & SING AGGREGATED B
     &  {NaN} &   1.00 &   10.83 & 2524.52 &   27.35 & aggregated   \\
CHL0 & 1 & SING SMALL & SING AGGREGATED S 
     &  {NaN} &   1.00 &    6.55 & 2524.52 &   16.54 & aggregated   \\
CHL2 & 1 & DECENTRAL & Decentral all run of river 
     &  {NaN} &   1.00 &   24.08 & 2524.52 &  60.80 & aggregated   \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
    \end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum:**
For completeness, let me added a case when table is split across two pages by use of the `xltabular`, `\small` font size and some additional small change of table design:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}

\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs, xltabular}
\newcommand\mcx[1]{\multicolumn{1}{>{\Centering}X}{#1}}
\usepackage{pdflscape}

\begin{document}
    \begin{landscape}
    \small
\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{b{#1}}
\begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{@{} *{2}{>{\Centering}b{3em}} 
                                  *{2}{l}
                                  *{5}{c}
                                  >{\centering\arraybackslash}X
                              @{} }
    \toprule
market area
    &   ag. unit
            &   hydro. system
                &   Hydro plant name
                        &   \mcx{Commi\-ssioning date}
                            &   \mcx{Hydraulic head [m]}
                                &   \mcx{Power turbine max [MW]}
                                    &   \mcx{Full load hours turbine}
                                        &   \mcx{Annual generation [GWh/a]}
                                                    &   Turbine type    \\
    \hline
\endfirsthead
    \toprule
market area
    &   ag. unit
            &   hydro. system
                &   Hydro plant name
                        &   \mcx{Commi\-ssioning date}
                            &   \mcx{Hydraulic head [m]}
                                &   \mcx{Power turbine max [MW]}
                                    &   \mcx{Full load hours turbine}
                                        &   \mcx{Annual generation [GWh/a]}
                                                    &   Turbine type    \\
    \hline
\endhead
    \hline
    \multicolumn{10}{r}{Continue on next page}\\ 
\endfoot
    \bottomrule
\endlastfoot
\rowcolor{gray!10}
\multicolumn{10}{l}{Hydro plant type: Conectividad, Conventional hydro storage} \\
    \hline
CHL1    & 0 & MAULE             & HE LOS CONDORES
        & 2023.0    &  480.00   & 150.00    & 3601.64   & 540.25    & Pelton    \\
CHL1    & 0 & MAULE             & HP LA MINA
        & 2018.0    &   64.82   &   36.70   & 1788.48   &   65.64   & Francis   \\
CHL1    & 0 & MAULE             & HP OJOS DE AGUA
        & 2008.0    &   65.96   &    8.98   & 4289.62   &   38.54   & Francis   \\
CHL1    & 0 & MAULE             & HP ISLA
        & 1963.0    &   92.11   &   69.00   & 4719.75   &  325.66   & Francis   \\
    \addlinespace
CHL1    & 0 & MAULE             &  HP CURILLINQUE
        & 1993.0    &  114.86   &   91.77   & 4227.24   &  387.93   & Francis   \\
CHL1    & 0 & MAULE             & HP LOMA ALTA
        & 1997.0    &   51.17   &   39.93   & 4172.54   &  166.62   & Francis   \\
CHL1    & 0 & MAULE             &  HP LOS HIERROS
        & 2014.0    &  102.35   &   25.00   & 3904.58   &   97.61   & Francis   \\
CHL1    & 0 & MAULE             & HP LOS HIERROS II
        & 2015.0    &   23.87   &    6.00   & 3085.52   &   18.51   & aggregated    \\
    \addlinespace
CHL1    & 0 & MAULE             & HP PEHUENCHE
        & 1991.0    &  202.43   &  568.29   & 2110.01   & 1199.10   & Francis   \\
CHL1    & 0 & MAULE             &  HE COLBUN
        & 1985.0    & 171.43    &  460.80   & 2965.72   & 1366.60   & Francis   \\
CHL1    & 0 & MAULE             & HP MACHICURA
        & 1985.0    &  37.53    &   94.76   & 3152.45   &  298.73   & aggregated    \\
CHL1    & 0 & MAULE             &  HP SAN IGNACIO
        & 1996.0    &  21.61    &   36.91   & 3191.41   &  117.81   & aggregated    \\
    \addlinespace
CHL1    & 0 & MAULE             & HP CHIBURGO
        & 2007.0    & 110.33    &   19.16   & 2767.31   &   53.01   & Francis   \\
CHL1    & 0 & MAULE             & HP SAN CLEMENTE
        & 2010.0    &  36.84    &    5.89   & 2201.96   &   12.96   & aggregated \\
CHL1    & 0 &  LAJA             & HE EL TORO
        & 1973.0    &  616.00   & 448.74    & 1807.75   &  811.21   & Pelton    \\
CHL1    & 0 &  LAJA             & HP ABANICO
        & 1948.0    &  136.47   &  92.71    & 2332.72   &  216.27   & Francis   \\
    \addlinespace
CHL1    & 0 &  LAJA             &  HE ANTUCO
        & 1981.0    &   181.95  & 319.17    & 3237.69   & 1033.37   & Francis   \\
CHL1    & 0 &  LAJA             & HP RUCUE
        & 1998.0    &  145.56   & 178.13    & 3306.83   &  589.05   & Francis   \\
CHL1    & 0 &  LAJA             & HP QUILLECO
        & 2007.0    &   62.55   &  70.65    & 3418.37   &  241.51   & Francis   \\
CHL1    & 0 &  LAJA             & HP LAJA I
        & 2015.0    &  15.58    &  34.06    & 1779.08   &   60.59   & aggregated    \\
    \addlinespace
CHL1    & 0 & BIO BIO           & HE RALCO
        & 2004.0    & 181.41    & 688.96    & 2481.89   & 1709.94   & Francis   \\
CHL1    & 0 & BIO BIO           & HP PALMUCHO
        & 2007.0    & 129.98    &  31.95    & 6031.07   & 192.70    & Francis   \\
CHL1    & 0 & BIO BIO           & HE PANGUE
        & 1996.0    &  90.98    & 465.83    & 2633.81   & 1226.91   & Francis   \\
CHL1    & 0 & BIO BIO           & HE ANGOSTURA
        & 2014.0   &  48.90     & 321.00    & 2802.40   & 899.57    & Francis   \\
    \addlinespace
CHL1    & 0 &  ACONCAGUA        & HP HORNITOS
        & 2008.0    & 568.67    &  60.85    & 2724.46   & 165.78    & Pelton    \\
CHL1    & 0 &  ACONCAGUA        & HP JUNCAL
        & 1994.0    & 250.20    &  32.00    & 7021.31   & 224.68    & Francis   \\
CHL1    & 0 &  ACONCAGUA        & HP BLANCO
        & 1993.0    & 655.07    &  52.87    & 2546.76   & 134.64    & Pelton    \\
CHL1    & 0 &  ACONCAGUA        & HP LOS QUILOS
        & 1943.0    & 216.07    &  39.80    & 4461.21   & 177.56    & Francis   \\
    \addlinespace
CHL1    & 0 &  ACONCAGUA        & HP CHACABUQUITO
        & 2002.0    & 138.76    &  25.64    & 3413.85   &  87.52    & Francis   \\
CHL1    & 0 &  TINGUIRIRICA I   & HP LA HIGUERA
        & 2011.0    & 354.84    & 154.61    & 2939.04   & 454.41    & Francis   \\
CHL1    & 0 & TINGUIRIRICA II   & HP LA CONFLUENCIA
        & 2011.0    & 353.72    & 162.79    & 2000.48   & 325.66    & Francis   \\
CHL1    & 0 & PILMAIQUEN        & HE PILMAIQUEN
        & 1944.0    &  30.70    &  40.68    & 4716.68   & 191.86    & aggregated    \\
    \addlinespace
CHL1    & 0 & PILMAIQUEN        & HP RUCATAYO
        & 2012.0    &  35.82    &  59.30    & 3490.90   & 207.01    & aggregated    \\
CHL1    & 0 & RAPEL             & HE RAPEL
        & 1986.0    &  70.49    & 376.64    & 1340.55   & 504.90    & Francis   \\
    \hline
\rowcolor{gray!10}
\multicolumn{10}{l}{Hydro plant type: Canutilar, Conventional hydro storage}    \\
    \hline
CHL1    & 0 & CANUTILAR         & HE CANUTILLAR
        & 1990.0    & 229.89    & 171.57    & 4066.02   & 697.61    & Francis   \\
    \hline
\rowcolor{gray!10}
\multicolumn{10}{l}{Hydro plant type: Run of the river}                         \\
    \hline
CHL1    & 1 &  SIC BIG          &  SIC AGGREGATED B
     &  {NaN}       &    1.00   & 1285.44   & 2945.27   & 3785.97   & aggregated    \\
CHL1    & 1 & SIC SMALL         & SIC AGGREGATED S
     &  {NaN}       &   1.00    &  511.61   & 2945.27   & 1506.84   & aggregated    \\
CHL0    & 1 & SING BIG          & SING AGGREGATED B
     &  {NaN}       &   1.00    &   10.83   & 2524.52   &   27.35   & aggregated    \\
CHL0    & 1 & SING SMALL        & SING AGGREGATED S
     &  {NaN}       &   1.00    &    6.55   & 2524.52   &   16.54   & aggregated    \\
CHL2    & 1 & DECENTRAL         & Decentral all run of river
     &  {NaN}       &   1.00    &   24.08   & 2524.52   &  60.80    & aggregated    \\
\end{xltabular}
    \end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hey @Zarko Thanks a lot for the recommendations! It is pretty helpful what you suggest in the code. I wonder if you know how to change the margins of just this page. I tried using \newgeometry and \enlargethispage, but it did not work very well. On your code [margin=20mm] work fine by compiling individually. In my big project it does not compile well. Do you have any recommendations? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Master_student_H2, you not provide any information of your document layout, so I just use one, which enable to fit table in page. Please, edit your question and add missed information. Than I would show how to use `changepage` package for increase text block size for this table.

Comment: @Zarko- Hey I just edited the packages that I'm using, not all of them because it might be to much to read, but at least the ones related to tables. Thank you!

Comment: @Master_student_H2, all what you need to do is add is `  `\scriptsize
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.95}`  after `\begin{sidewaystable}` or enable that table can split across two packages. Let me know, if this can be an option.

Comment: ! Works smoothly! THANK YOU so much. It saved me and the recommendations were great to. Have a nice day!

Comment: @Master_student_H2, see addendum. BTW, if answer solve your problem, you may consider to accept it (by clicking on the check mark at top left side of answer). As I see, so far you not accepted any of received answers ... does no one of them solve your problems?

Comment: thanks for letting me know, I did not know, I could/should do the accept answer!